# My code has a textarea which is not expanding to fill the entire div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My code has a textarea which is not expanding to fill the entire div. When I use developer tools in Chrome I see this (edit:this is system generated):
[image]

Can I make the textarea fill the entire div. My markup is as follows:

```
    <div class="segment container-fluid" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <div class="row" style="padding-left:3em;">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-12" for="notes" style="text-align:left; width:300px"> Notes (max 255 characters)</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="width:800px;">
                    <textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="6" value="" style="width:800px;" class="form-control col-sm-12"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: something in CSS is preventing my textarea by setting max width to 280. Is there a workaround.

Comment: you set a width of 800px to an element with a max-width of 280px. Set a different max-width if you want the `<textarea>` to become wider.

Comment: The max-width is system generated. I did not set it. Thats my question. Did u even read the question?

Comment: It's people like you who prevent users from asking questions. Why did you down vote my question?

Comment: You never said this is system generated in the question... Also, don't assume someone downvoted your question. It has had 11 views, ie 11 different people that could have downvoted it.

Comment: Does that merit a downvote Tim?

Comment: I did not downvote your question, even though it's qualified for it. Also, you are welcome.

Comment: @UA – Arguing in the comments isn't going to garner you any sympathy.  We understood your question, and you have answers to review.  I hope you find a solution to your problem, but having a seemingly hostile attitude towards someone who didn't understand the your problem might not be the best course of action.

Comment: @NicoO This is what you get for trying to help eh?

Comment: Any constructive answers guys?

Comment: Both Nico and Tim, you did not read the question and simply hit down vote. Can't tell the reason for your negative attitude but look at the accepted answer. Worked for me. :)

Comment: We read the question *as you wrote it.* We both decided to stop helping as soon as you became hostile. Nice to see a good professional attitude from you. Keep that up.

Comment: @TimLewis – I do like how he changed the accepted answer and removed the comment thanking me from my answer after he realized I warned him against getting hostile in the comments, though.  Haha.  Can't win with some people.

Comment: @JoshBurgess Wow. That is a class act right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the div have more width than the max-width of textarea that is not possible. You have change the max-width of the textarea as per the width of the div.

Answer (score 1):

Yup.  Right after your `width: 800px` line just set `max-width: none`.

Example:

```
<textarea id="notes" name="notes" rows="6" value="" style="width:800px; max-width: none;" class="form-control col-sm-12"></textarea>
```